# Understanding this JAVA code and how to programmatically login to website

Tags: java, json, apache

I am trying to understand this code that will attempt to log in to a website based on the log in information provided. There is a part that does not seem to be working. What exactly is a NUCLEUS_ID_PATTERN and what is trying to accomplish?

I thought I could try and understand it after awhile but there is not much out there to help me understand and I am a little lost. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
public final class LoginRequest
/*     */ {
/*     */   private static final int NUCLLUES_ID_MATCH_GROUP = 1;
/*  49 */   public static final Pattern NUCLEUS_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".* userid\\s*:\\s*\"(\\d+)\".*");
/*     */ 
/*     */   public static void makeLogin(String email, String password)
/*     */     throws HttpException, IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException
/*     */   {
/*  66 */     HttpClient client = ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().getClient();
/*     */ 
/*  68 */     HttpGet loginGet = new HttpGet("https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app");
/*  69 */     HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
/*     */ 
/*  71 */     HttpResponse response = client.execute(loginGet, context);
/*     */ 
/*  73 */     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
/*  74 */       throw new IOException(response.getStatusLine().toString());
}
/*  75 */     HttpUriRequest currentReq = (HttpUriRequest)context.getAttribute("http.request");
/*  76 */     HttpHost currentHost = (HttpHost)context.getAttribute("http.target_host");
/*     */ 
/*  78 */     String currentUrl = currentHost.toURI() + currentReq.getURI();
/*     */ 
/*  82 */     ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(response);
/*     */ 
/*  85 */     HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost(currentUrl);
/*  86 */     List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
/*     */ 
/*  88 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
/*  89 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
/*  90 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_eventId", "submit"));
/*  91 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_rememberMe", "on"));
/*  92 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberMe", "on"));
/*  93 */     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("facebookAuth", ""));
/*     */ 
/*  95 */     loginPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
/*     */ 
/*  98 */     loginPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
/*     */ 
/* 101 */     HttpResponse loginResponse = client.execute(loginPost);
/*     */ 
/* 104 */     String nucluesIdSource = ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(loginResponse);
/* 105 */     Long nucluesId = Long.valueOf(0L);
/*     */ 
/* 107 */     Matcher matcher = NUCLEUS_ID_PATTERN.matcher(nucluesIdSource);
/* 108 */     if (matcher.matches()) {
/* 109 */       nucluesId = Long.valueOf(Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1)));
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 113 */     HttpGet localeRequest = new HttpGet("https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app");
//            HttpGet localeRequest = new HttpGet("http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/?locale=en_GB&baseShowoffUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team%2Fshow-off&guest_app_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team");
/* 114 */     HttpResponse localeResponse = client.execute(localeRequest);
/*     */ 
/* 116 */     ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(localeResponse);
/*     */ 
/* 118 */     LoginResponse loginInfo = new LoginResponse();
/* 119 */     loginInfo.setNucleusId(nucluesId.longValue());
/*     */ 
/* 121 */     SessionManager.INSTANCE().setLoginResponse(loginInfo);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public static void downloadAccountInfo()
/*     */     throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
/*     */   {
/* 132 */     String url = String.format("https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app");
/*     */ 
/* 134 */     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
/*     */       
/* 137 */     String xRoute = "https://utas.fut.ea.com:443";
/* 138 */     addStandardHeaders(request, xRoute);
/*     */ 
/* 140 */     HttpResponse response = ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().getClient().execute(request);
/*     */     
/* 145 */     ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().checkResponseHeadersForCookies(response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie"));
/*     */ 
/* 150 */     String result = ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(response);
/*     */           
/* 151 */       shard1JsonResp = new JSONObject(result);  //Error here probably due to bad link
/*     */       
/* 154 */     HttpGet repeatRequest = new HttpGet(url);
/* 155 */     addStandardHeaders(repeatRequest, "https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com:443");
/* 156 */     HttpResponse repeatResponse = ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().getClient().execute(repeatRequest);
/*     */ 
/* 158 */     result = ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(repeatResponse);
/* 159 */     JSONObject shard2JsonResp = new JSONObject(result);
/*     */ 
/* 161 */     JSONObject jsonResp = null;
/* 162 */     if (!shard2JsonResp.has("debug")) {
/* 163 */       jsonResp = shard2JsonResp;
/* 164 */       xRoute = "https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com:443";
/*     */     } else {
/* 166 */       jsonResp = shard1JsonResp;
/* 167 */       xRoute = "https://utas.fut.ea.com:443";
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 175 */     AccountInfo accInf = new AccountInfo();
/*     */ 
/* 179 */     JSONObject accountInfo = jsonResp.getJSONObject("userAccountInfo");
/* 180 */     JSONArray personasArray = accountInfo.getJSONArray("personas");
/* 181 */     accInf.getPersonasList().addAll(getPersonas(personasArray));
/*     */ 
/* 184 */     SessionManager.INSTANCE().setxUtRoute(xRoute);
/* 185 */     SessionManager.INSTANCE().setAccountInfo(accInf);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   private static List<Persona> getPersonas(JSONArray personasArray) throws JSONException {
/* 189 */     List personaList = new ArrayList(personasArray.length());
/* 190 */     for (int i = 0; i < personasArray.length(); i++) {
/* 191 */       JSONObject personas = personasArray.getJSONObject(i);
/*     */ 
/* 193 */       Persona p = new Persona();
/*     */ 
/* 195 */       p.setPersonaId(personas.getLong("personaId"));
/* 196 */       p.setPersonaName(personas.getString("personaName"));
/*     */ 
/* 200 */       JSONArray userClubArray = personas.getJSONArray("userClubList");
/*     */ 
/* 202 */       for (int j = 0; j < userClubArray.length(); j++) {
/* 203 */         JSONObject userClub = userClubArray.getJSONObject(j);
/*     */ 
/* 205 */         UserClub uc = new UserClub();
/*     */ 
/* 207 */         uc.setYear(userClub.getString("year"));
/* 208 */         uc.setPlatform(userClub.getString("platform"));
/* 209 */         uc.setClubName(userClub.getString("clubName"));
/* 210 */         uc.setClubAbbr(userClub.getString("clubAbbr"));
/* 211 */         uc.setEstablished(userClub.getString("established"));
/* 212 */         uc.setLastAccessTime(userClub.getString("lastAccessTime"));
/* 213 */         uc.setBadgeId(userClub.getString("badgeId"));
/*     */ 
/* 216 */         p.getUserClubList().add(uc);
/*     */       }
/*     */ 
/* 219 */       personaList.add(p);
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 223 */     return personaList;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   private static void addStandardHeaders(HttpGet request, String routerUrl) {
/* 227 */     request.addHeader("Accept", "text/json");
/* 228 */     request.addHeader("Host", "www.easports.com");
/* 229 */     request.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/?baseShowoffUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team%2Fshow-off&guest_app_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team&locale=en_GB");
/*     */ 
/* 232 */     request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
/* 233 */     request.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
/* 234 */     request.addHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
/* 235 */     request.addHeader("X-UT-Route", routerUrl);
/* 236 */     request.addHeader("Easw-Session-Data-Nucleus-Id", String.valueOf(SessionManager.INSTANCE().getLoginResponse().getNucleusId()));
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public static void authenticationRequest(LoginResponse loginResp, Persona persona)
/*     */     throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
/*     */   {
/* 253 */     String authJson = String.format("{ \"isReadOnly\": false, \"sku\": \"FUT15WEB\", \"clientVersion\": 1, \"nuc\": %1$s, \"nucleusPersonaId\": %2$s, \"nucleusPersonaDisplayName\": \"%3$s\", \"nucleusPersonaPlatform\": \"%4$s\", \"locale\": \"en-GB\", \"method\": \"authcode\", \"priorityLevel\":4, \"identification\": { \"authCode\": \"\" } }", new Object[] { Long.valueOf(loginResp.getNucleusId()), Long.valueOf(persona.getPersonaId()), persona.getPersonaName(), persona.getLastVisitedUserClub().getPlatform() });
/*     */ 
/* 256 */     String path = "http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/p/ut/auth";
/*     */ 
/* 258 */     HttpPost authenticatePost = new HttpPost(path);
/* 259 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript;");
/* 260 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Host", "www.easports.com");
/* 261 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.5");
/* 262 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/?baseShowoffUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team%2Fshow-off&guest_app_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team&locale=en_GB");
/*     */ 
/* 266 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
/*     */ 
/* 268 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
/* 269 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
/* 270 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("X-UT-Route", SessionManager.INSTANCE().getxUtRoute());
/* 271 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Easw-Session-Data-Nucleus-Id", String.valueOf(loginResp.getNucleusId()));
/* 272 */     authenticatePost.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
/*     */ 
/* 274 */     authenticatePost.setEntity(new StringEntity(authJson));
/*     */ 
/* 276 */     HttpResponse response = ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().getClient().execute(authenticatePost);
/*     */ 
/* 278 */     String result = ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(response);
/*     */ 
/* 284 */     AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
/*     */ 
/* 286 */     JSONObject jsonResp = new JSONObject(result);
/*     */ 
/* 288 */     authenticationResponse.setProtocol(jsonResp.getString("protocol"));
/* 289 */     authenticationResponse.setIpPort(jsonResp.getString("ipPort"));
/* 290 */     authenticationResponse.setServerTime(jsonResp.getString("serverTime"));
/* 291 */     authenticationResponse.setLastOnlineTime(jsonResp.getString("lastOnlineTime"));
/* 292 */     authenticationResponse.setSessionId(jsonResp.getString("sid"));
/*     */ 
/* 294 */     SessionManager.INSTANCE().setAuthenticationResponse(authenticationResponse);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public static void validateSecurityAnswer(AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse, String securityAnswer)
/*     */     throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
/*     */   {
/* 309 */     String url = "http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/p/ut/game/fifa15/phishing/validate";
/*     */ 
/* 311 */     HttpPost validatePost = new HttpPost(url);
/*     */ 
/* 313 */     validatePost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript;");
/* 314 */     validatePost.addHeader("Host", "www.easports.com");
/* 315 */     validatePost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.5");
/* 316 */     validatePost.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.easports.com/iframe/fut/?baseShowoffUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team%2Fshow-off&guest_app_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easports.com%2Fuk%2Ffifa%2Ffootball-club%2Fultimate-team&locale=en_GB");
/*     */ 
/* 320 */     validatePost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
/*     */ 
/* 322 */     validatePost.addHeader("Easw-Session-Data-Nucleus-Id", String.valueOf(SessionManager.INSTANCE().getLoginResponse().getNucleusId()));
/*     */ 
/* 324 */     validatePost.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
/* 325 */     validatePost.addHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
/* 326 */     validatePost.addHeader("X-UT-Route", SessionManager.INSTANCE().getxUtRoute());
/* 327 */     validatePost.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
/* 328 */     validatePost.setHeader("X-UT-SID", authenticationResponse.getSessionId());
/* 329 */     validatePost.setHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
/*     */ 
/* 331 */     List params = new ArrayList();
/* 332 */     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", HasherUtil.getHash(securityAnswer)));
/* 333 */     validatePost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
/*     */ 
/* 335 */     HttpResponse response = ConnectionManager.INSTANCE().getClient().execute(validatePost);
/*     */ 
/* 337 */     String result = ResponseReaderUtil.readHttpResponse(response);
/*     */ 
/* 339 */     ValidateResponse validateResponse = new ValidateResponse();
/*     */ 
/* 341 */     JSONObject jsonResp = new JSONObject(result); 
/*     */ 
/* 343 */     validateResponse.setDebug(jsonResp.getString("debug"));
/* 344 */     validateResponse.setString(jsonResp.getString("string"));
/* 345 */     validateResponse.setString(jsonResp.getString("reason"));
/* 346 */     validateResponse.setToken(jsonResp.getString("token"));
/* 347 */     validateResponse.setCode(jsonResp.getInt("code"));
/*     */ 
/* 349 */     SessionManager.INSTANCE().setValidateResponse(validateResponse);
/*     */   }
/*     */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the forum Mnazanda.  The static Pattern NUCLEUS_ID_PATTERN is an object use for regular expressiosn (I suggest you research these) and may be used in compliance with a Matcher object to match char sequences against these regular expressions. In that code provided, this variable is used with a matcher object to parse the Html code for a long value that is used in the login response.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That's making a little more sense now. What would the long value be used for? What is its significance?

Comment: I see it used in line 119, try researching the loginInfo class